# Show a loading message for a Magento Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, magento, splash-screen, ajax-request

How do I display the orange leading message with the animated spinning gif when an Ajax request takes place on the frontend? I already make the request and so on, I just want to add the loading screen. I am calling *new Ajax.Request...* in my JavaScript function, do I have to add it there?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing this in admin then the theme already does it automatically. If it fails check your browser's console for javascript errors.

Comment: No, its on the frontend. I guess its not done automatically there?

Comment: You'll have to create your own using [`Ajax.Responders`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/), but be aware it will affect all `Ajax.Request` objects. The good news is you can use the adminhtml theme for inspiration.

Comment: Yes, this does what I want. I created some div which is shown on onCreate and hidden on onComplete. How do I display the div in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I solved it using some CSS, thanks, **solved**.

Comment: @EOB post your solution as answer and marked it. It helps other

Answer (score 0):

Use `onCreate` and `onSuccess`:

```
 new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/url')->sessionUrlVar(Mage::getUrl('get/my/apples')) ?>', 
 {
            parameters: {isAjax: 1, page: 3, method: 'POST'},
            onCreate: function(request) {$('gID').innerHTML = 'loading...';},                                                                                            
            onSuccess: function(transport) {                                         
                  $('gID').innerHTML = transport.responseText;           
            }                                                                        
 });
```